# Google auth from Chrome extension after switching to v3

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-api, gmail-api, google-signin

I'm writing a Chrome extension that will access Gmail API, and I need proper authorization for it. All code examples involve referencing their API Javascript library which loads their oauth library dynamically, like `gapi.load('auth2', ...)`. However, after switching to the v3 manifest, they are going to forbid executing downloaded code, so the only option would be to include the required scripts with the extension.

How do I implement it? Would I have to implement calling the API endpoints myself?